# Ajax call with PHP / MySQLi query returning wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

I am trying to check if an input value already exists in my database.

So far I got the following but this always returns me "Invalid" (even if I enter a matching value) so my guess is I have an error in the part after my SELECT query or in my If Else logic.

Can someone tell me how to do this right?

**My JS:**

```
$('#btnCheck').click(function() {   
    var username = $('#username').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'userSubmit.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {username: username},
        success: function(response){
            if(response == 'valid') {
                alert('Valid');
            } else {
                alert('Invalid');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**My PHP:**

```
$username = $_POST['username'];      
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Error: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "valid";
} else {
    echo "invalid";
}
```

Comment: What's the actual value of `$stmt->num_rows` ?

Comment: Have you watched the request/response in the browser's developer tools to see what is actually returned?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die($conn->connect_error);` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: One final note on your recent question. you don't use while on arrays. with fetch_all you have to use foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `store_result()` in order for the number of rows to actually be recorded before calling `num_rows`:

```
...
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    ...
```

The reason why you must call `store_result()` is that without this, no results have actually been fetched, and the number of rows (`num_rows`) will therefore be `0`.

Reference the official documentation for `num_rows`:

> Returns the number of rows in the result set. The use of
>   mysqli_stmt_num_rows() depends on whether or not you used
>   mysqli_stmt_store_result() to buffer the entire result set in the
>   statement handle.

A link to this is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what was missing here ! One more question: It still does not recognise my result as this seems to contain a symbol in front of the text that I echo in PHP ("valid" / "invalid"). When I alert it in JQuery it shows me this symbol in front of my text. How can I get rid of this so that the result is only my text ?

Comment: @keewee279 Regarding your other question, I think that is probably worth asking separately.  However, it'd be very odd to have a symbol\character appearing before your return values if you have not `echo`'d it in the PHP code.  Make sure to include an example in your new question please

Comment: It still returns me Invalid as per my comment before. I only see a differece now when alerting the result but otherwise still get Invalid for any value.

Comment: @keewee279 That's odd.  Have you tried dumping the value of `num_rows` in your PHP to see what it contains? The SQL statement should return at least 1 row if the username matches

Comment: @keewee279 I've also noticed that you are reusing the `$username` variable for both the `$_POST` output and also your `$conn`.  Could that be complicating the issue?

Comment: Yes, it seems to return me spaces or some other invisible characters in front of my text so e.g. instead of "Invalid" it returns " invalid". I don't see where this could happen. It actually contains more than one space, this just gets removed on the site here.

Comment: It seemed I had to trim the output, not sure why but then it works with your solution so I'll accept it now. Thanks again for your help !

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to use `num_rows`, which not only is confusing, easy to misuse, but also could cause performance issues if misused.

Just fetch `COUNT(1)` and then fetch a single column from the first row in your SQL result.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
$stmt->execute();
$exists = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row()[0];

if($exists) {
    echo "valid";
} else {
    echo "invalid";
}
```

If you wanted for some strange reason to stick with `num_rows` you would either have to call `store_result()` on the statement and then get the `num_rows` from the statement or call `get_result()` and read the value of `num_rows` on the returned result set.