# Why or how parameterized queries prevent SQL injection?

Tags: .net, security, sql-injection

Lets say I want to read user data from a table when user provides username and password.

My plain text query looks like this:

```
select * from Users where UserName = '{THIS WILL BE PROVIDED BY USER}' and Password = '{THIS WILL BE PROVIDED BY USER}';
```

Now I use SQL parameters to prevent SQL injection problem with the aforementioned query:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = $"select * from Users where UserName = @UserName and Password = @Password";
        command.Connection = connection;

        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        parameter.Value = "{THIS WILL BE PROVIDED BY USER}";
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        parameter2.Value = "{THIS WILL BE PROVIDED BY USER}";
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter2);
```

If I use the typical value like this `' OR 1=1 --` to reproduce the SQL injection, it does not work with parameterized query.

**Why parameterized queries are able to prevent SQL injection?**

Though query is parameterized, eventually it has to be turned into a "usual" query at the time of execution. When we are setting the malicious value for a parameter, why does not it take effect?

What happens under the hood?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58419045/285587) will give you the idea

Comment: Actually, this answer is significantly better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection